# Convert decimal number as time in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I'm trying to find a way to display a decimal number as a time format in Google Data Studio. For example, 0.5 should be 0:30, 0.9 as 0:54 and so on. This is possible in Google Sheets whenever you divide the decimal number by 24 and change the cell formatting of the division to a time format. I would need to display this numbers and actually add them whenever new data comes in whereas 0:30 + 0:54 should be 1:24. Is this something that is possible to do in Google Data Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved by creating a value in **Seconds** and setting the Field Type to **Duration (Sec.)**:

### 1) Calculated Field

Creating a [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) (where `Field` represents the respective field name):

```
Field * 60
```

### 2) Field Type

Setting the **Field Type** to:

```
Number > Duration (Sec.)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/2a3a725f-71b9-4e30-b4a4-4d87a85b2de7) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]